# Make a black and white image turn to color on hover - HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: html, css, image, css-animations, responsive-images

Does anyone know how to make black and white images animate to color when you hover over them. This would be like digitally revealing a painting or doing a text fill animation if that makes sense. It's an idea I have for a project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For future reference, "I haven't tried anything yet" is a sure fire way to not get any answers.

Comment: One way to try things is to get yourself a JSFiddle or CodePen account. They make it very easy to try out code. https://jsfiddle.net https://codepen.io/

Comment: To those who have closed this question as a duplicate, I believe the OP was asking not about simply switching between B+W and color, but **animating** the switch. In which case a better resource is [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2023/09/revealing-images-css-mask-animations/).

Comment: Voting to reopen as the post given as a duplicate does not cover animation (as pointed out by @BrettDonald) and it contains some fairly (in 2024) awful ways round the b/w to color problem. The answer here from @artlung answers the question well and will be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function) function [`saturate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/saturate) which gives the ability to control the saturation of the colors on an element. Along with a `transition` you get the effect of animation.

```css
a.colorful {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
   90deg,
   red,
   orange,
   yellow,
   green,
   blue,
   indigo,
   violet
  );
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-width: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
  filter: saturate(0);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
a.colorful:hover {
  filter: saturate(1);
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="colorful">Hello!</a>
```

Comment: The OP was asking about *animating* the switch.

Comment: @BrettDonald  It is animated, but only for 0.2s ...